# How to add radio buttons to the slides in powerpoint presentation

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I create a Powerpoint add-in in .NET and I know how to add new textbox to the slide. But I don´t know how to add radio buttons, check buttons and input text fields. Is it possible?

```
private void questions()
{
PowerPoint.Shape textBox = activeSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(Office.MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 50, 50, 500, 500);
textBox.TextFrame.TextRange.InsertAfter("Text");
}
```

Comment: Is this a programming question?  PowerPoint isn't something I typically expect to see someone programming in...  (Although, I suppose it probably has VBA available, so it's possible this ***is*** a programming question.)

Comment: Yes I programming in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you'd do it in VBA.  I'll leave the VBA 2 C# translation work to you.

```
Dim oSl As Slide
Dim oSh As Shape
Set oSl = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
Set oSh = oSl.Shapes.AddOLEObject(100, 100, 200, 30, "Forms.OptionButton.1")
```

More info:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb230698(v=office.12).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb230698%28v=office.12%29.aspx)